# rails_sql_views undefined method 'base_tables' on mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create views and found that using SQL to create them caused problems running tests.

On my development system, which is sqlite3, I rolled back my database migrations to before the views were created.

I added rails_sql_views gem from git://github.com/unleashed/rails_sql_views.

I modified my migration for the view so it is now

```
def up
 # dividing by 100 for percentages and 1000 for kW, hence 100000
create_view :view_sub_power_ratings,
  "select
        ((s.power_off * p.percent_off + s.standby * p.percent_standby + s.idle * p.percent_idle + s.normal * p.percent_normal + s.maximum * p.percent_max) * p.working_days * 24 +
        (s.power_off * percent_off_nw + s.standby * percent_standby_nw + s.idle * p.percent_idle_nw + s.normal * p.percent_normal_nw + s.maximum * percent_max_nw) * (365 - p.working_days) * 24) /100000
                                                               as power_usage,
        p.subscription_id,
        s.device_id
    from sub_category_params p
    inner join devices d on d.device_category_id = p.device_category_id
    inner join device_power_summaries s on  s.device_id = d.id"

# dividing by 100 for percentage accuracy, 100  for percent used, and 1000 for kW, hence 10000000


create_view :view_sub_power_ratings_variations,

"select

(s.standby * s.standby_accuracy * p.percent_standby + s.idle * s.idle_accuracy *p.percent_idle + s.normal * s.normal_accuracy * p.percent_normal +
 s.maximum * s.maximum_accuracy * p.percent_max + s.power_off * s.power_off_accuracy * p.percent_off) * 24 * p.working_days/ 10000000 as variation_wd,

(s.standby * s.standby_accuracy * p.percent_standby_nw + s.idle * s.idle_accuracy *p.percent_idle_nw + s.normal * s.normal_accuracy * p.percent_normal_nw +
 s.maximum * s.maximum_accuracy * p.percent_max_nw + s.power_off * s.power_off_accuracy * p.percent_off_nw) * 24 * (365-p.working_days)/ 10000000 as variation_nw,
        p.subscription_id,
        s.device_id
    from sub_category_params p
    inner join devices d on d.device_category_id = p.device_category_id
    inner join device_power_summaries s on  s.device_id = d.id"

  create_view :view_sub_power_maximums,
  "select
    r.power_usage + (v.variation_nw + v.variation_wd) as maximum_power_usage,
    r.power_usage - (v.variation_nw + v.variation_wd)   as minimum_power_usage,
          v.subscription_id,
        v.device_id
    from sub_category_params p
    inner join devices d on d.device_category_id = p.device_category_id
    inner join device_power_summaries s on  s.device_id = d.id
    inner join view_sub_power_ratings r on d.id = r.device_id and p.subscription_id = r.subscription_id
    inner join view_sub_power_ratings_variations v on  d.id = v.device_id and p.subscription_id = v.subscription_id"

end

def down
  drop_view :view_sub_power_ratings
  drop_view :view_sub_power_ratings_variations
  drop_view :view_sub_power_maximums
end
```

I then ran the migration again and all was fine. Views are created and the create_view is in schema.rb. Result!

However, on deploying to my staging server I'm getting an error on the migration. This is on MySQL2.

This is the trace

```
** Execute db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
undefined method `base_tables' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xb876f1c>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bundler/gems/rails_sql_views-9d781715bcab/lib/rails_sql_views/schema_dumper.rb:98:in `tables_with_views_excluded'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb:27:in `dump'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bundler/gems/rails_sql_views-9d781715bcab/lib/rails_sql_views/schema_dumper.rb:27:in `dump_with_views'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb:21:in `dump'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:354:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:352:in `open'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:352:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties /databases.rake:161:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'  
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:156:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'   
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
```

My Gemfile has

```
gem 'rails_sql_views', :git => 'git://github.com/unleashed/rails_sql_views', require: 'rails_sql_views'
```

The bundle install runs ok:

```
 ** [out :: myserver.com] 
 ** [out :: myserver.com] Using rails_sql_views (0.8.0.1.unleashed) from git://github.com/unleashed/rails_sql_views (at master)
 ** [out :: myserver.com] 
 ** [out :: myserver.com] Using sass (3.1.15)
 ** [out :: myserver.com] * mysql2-0.3.11.gem
 ** [out :: myserver.com] Removing outdated .gem files from vendor/cache
 ** [out :: myserver.com] * rails_sql_views-0.8.0.gem
 ** [out :: myserver.com] Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
  command finished in 4018ms
```

I've seen some people reporting similar and the explanation has been that there is no adaptor for MySQL2. But it is there in the lib/rails_sql_views/connection_adapters directory : mysql2_adapter.rb

I've taken a peek and there is a method for base_tables

So what am I missing? Sorry, I know its going to be something quite obvious but I've still not quite got my head round how gems are integrated into the system.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the source of the gem to:

git://github.com/centresource/rails_sql_views

and this has resolved the problem - the migration is now working ok

Answer (score 0):

When you add a gem to your Gemfile you need to run `bundle install`.

This will see if your Gemfile has changed and if it has, for example adding a new gem, it will go out to the source, pull in the gem code and then include that in your application.

To see what gems the project has just look at the Gemfile.lock file that was generated from the last bundle.

Comment: The bundle install is run as part of the deployment, under Capistrano. It does that ok with no errors, but when it runs the migration part of the deployment, I see the above error

Comment: Is the gem now included in the Gemfile.lock file on staging?

Comment: I don't think its a bundler problem as the trace shows it is in the rails_sql_views/schema_dumper.rb code, it is finding and executing the Gem. Its as though the additional functionality provided for the Connector isn't getting included - more like I need a require somewhere

Comment: Hi, Michael - yes, it appears under dependencies as: rails_sql_views!

Comment: It also appears at the top:  GIT
  remote: git://github.com/unleashed/rails_sql_views
  revision: 9d781715bcab9842754ae8dc3c3b3799c03d112e
  specs:
    rails_sql_views (0.8.0.1.unleashed)
      activerecord